# Applying checkmarks to certain tableView rows based on JSON criteria

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to create a conditional statement that decides if a tableView record will show a checkmark accessory.

The checkmark should automatically be applied to appropriate records if the condition is met.

**The following is what I have in my cellForRowAt:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
```

**The JSON structure is defined as the following:**

```
var structure = [JSONStructure]()

struct JSONStructure: Codable {
    var peron: String
    var update: Int
}
```

The JSON will either show update as either a number 100 or 200.
If the `update` equals 100 a checkmark should show for that record

But if the record has an `update` equal to 200 no checkmark should show for that record.

Can something like this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

What have you done so far?

This can be done using a simple condition in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (update == 100) {
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```